# Is it worth paying for Joomla security extensions?

Tags: php, security, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I'm finishing my first website in Joomla, it has maybe 5 or 6 forms (register, login, search, newletter, ...) and we also have comments on articles, a questions/answers section, tests section and a form to send sms.

I'd like to know according to your experience and knowledge if we should (must?) or not buy one of those security extensions like RSFirewall! or SecureLive Badges and Seals or any other. Is not enough protection using free extensions and following the advices/guides (php) provided in stackoverflow (or somewhere else) to protect joomla made websites ?

Thanks in advance for your help (and time)!

Comment: I think this mostly depends on your budget, how much critical information you have on the website, imortance of 'uptime' for your online business etc. But I would say, for %99 of websites out there this is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is no.  As long as you're smart and keep the software updated, those extensions don't really add any practical value (In my experience anyway).

Follow sound principals, and stay vigilant and that'll be worth more than any of these "tools" any day of the week.

Comment: This is not a 100% true, it does provide partial protection from 0-day exploits. But you are correct about the rest, all and all the benefit won't outweight the cost most of the time if you take proper precautions

Comment: @Cyber: Can you explain how it provides protection against 0-day exploits?

Comment: well it examines the requests made by user, and blocks them if suspicious strings like `union select`, or `<script>alert(/xss/)</script>` (just very simple examples...) are found. So for instance if you have RSFirewall in place, and blind sql injection is discovered in other installed module, the RSFirewall will still block request attempting to extract information from the database, before a patch is released for the module in question.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is protected by its community :D and keep on updates and don't use not recommended Extensions or avoid using extension at all if you can, and you should be safe and sound!
While you should also look for other stuff on your server too, cause if someone likes to damage your site they need access to files server or/and database and it really dons't matter how they get there for you to have a Bad time!

Answer (score 0):

For my joomla based sites I found it most useful to use an [cloud-based security solution called incapsula](http://www.incapsula.com/) as this also blocks different types of spammers, and I can zoom in to problematic areas in my sites with this tool. Some solutions have built-in CDN, and they give it all for free.